# Jersery @FormDataParam and FormDataContentDisposition is not working even after adding maven dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, jersey, jax-rs

I have added these 3 maven dependency. But when i try to use @FormDataParam and FormDataContentDisposition its showing red mark as it is not found. But I can see that in the multipart lib I am attaching image for reference.

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

[image: This is its showing when i try to import multipart]

[image: Its showing FormDataParam and FormDataContentDisposition classes in maven dependencies as marked]

Comment: You might need to refresh your project or something. Maybe close eclipse and reopen. I don't know, I don't really use Eclipse. But it's definitely an Eclipse problem. And you didn't import FormDataContentDisposition.

Comment: Thanks for response.I tried to restart eclipse ..Still same problem ...and even (Ctrl + space )auto suggestion not coming for both the classes. Might be eclipse problem

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use?

Comment: eclipse oxygen.3a

Comment: Add the FormDataContentDisposition import, then try to build it from the command line and see what happens. `mvn clean package`.

Comment: Thanks Paul its working now .. something went wrong with build path seems maven was not automatically configuring the jars in build path....now its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after adding dependency in maven it was not working .. Then it showed me suggestion to fix project on the error statement,on clicking that suggestion it asked to add org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart library to build . Then i simply selected it and ok....It started working